# Why are style classes stored in a List instead of a Set?

Tags: css, javafx

I was recently toying around with CSS in JavaFX and noticed that I got the same style multiple times in the style list of my node.

Since the order of the styles is defined by the order in the css file and not by the order of the list that getStyleClass() of a node returns, I was wondering if there is a special reason for that.

Example:

application.css

```
.bg-color-1 {
    -fx-background-color:red; 
}
.bg-color-2 {
    -fx-background-color:green;
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

            root.getStyleClass().add( "bg-color-1");
            root.getStyleClass().add( "bg-color-2");

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if you write

```
    root.getStyleClass().add( "bg-color-1");
    root.getStyleClass().add( "bg-color-2");
```

or change the order to

```
    root.getStyleClass().add( "bg-color-2");
    root.getStyleClass().add( "bg-color-1");
```

The used style will always be the last in the css file, i. e. "bg-color-2".

**Question**

Why is a List used instead of a Set?

Comment: I actually find this a real pain: you end up cluttering your code with checks of the form `if (! styleClasses.contains(...))` almost any time you add classes to the list of style classes; a set would be much more convenient (and would perform better). Maybe there is some use case where having the same class in the list multiple times is desirable, but I have no idea what that might be...

Comment: The styles not being applied in a order they have been added looks like a bug to me. You may file it.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's the same way that html handles it as well afaik. The thing that bothers me is what James_D mentions. You always have to check first before you add a new style class. The bug is imo that a List is used instead of a Set. Unless there is some reason.

Comment: Try asking the [openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev), you may receive a canonical answer.

Comment: I asked the openjfx-dev mailing list as suggested. Interested ones can read the answers [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2015-May/017271.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a css Standard. 
Your root object contains both Style classes.

The Css-Parser or Render or IDK (The thing that evaulates the css) reads the CSS-File from Top to Bottom.

That means it changes the Backgroundcolor to red and than to green.

so if you remove the 'bg-color-2' from the root it'll be red otherwise it will be green.